# Resources on History of Programming Languages, Specifically Java

Tags: java, history

I have a student working on his high school senior thesis.  He is interested in the history of programming languages, specifically Java, and he's looking for resources detailing that history.  He's looking to answer these kinds of questions:

- Why was Java created?  What problems was it meant to address?
- Did it successfully address those problems?  How so/why not?
- Whether or not it addressed the problems it was designed to solve, why did Java become so popular?
- What problems, if any, did Java create?  What are its shortcomings and/or deficiencies?
- Where and in what contexts is Java still relevant?
- Where has it lost its relevancy?  Why, and to what?

By the (admittedly arcane) school rules of writing one's senior thesis, he is allowed at most two web-based resources, and he must have at least five resources total (so at least three must be printed-on-paper resources, whether they be books or journal articles).  Any recommendations?

Please do not hesitate to recommend online resources, especially since well-written sources can often help point the way towards the next avenue of exploration.  But we're having the most trouble trying to find printed resources, so any help along these lines would be most appreciated.

To be clear, I'm not asking here for answers to these questions (sadly, my school does not consider SO to be a valid resource), and I'm decidedly *not* asking "Why is Java awesome/terrible?".  I'm looking for resources I can point my student to so that he can do some research that the school will recognize as valid.

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Comment: This might be more appropriate as a community wiki "question", given the subjectivity of answers and that selecting a single answer wouldn't really make sense.  Finally, to be mildly pedantic: shouldn't the student be posting this question?  With some guidance from you, sure, but anyone looking to "do" technology should get an early start participating in the various communities.  Mild criticisms aside, looks like a great project, best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've already tried this but [wikipedias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_programming_language)piece of the history of java would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Rod Johnson in his [Java: Expert One-on-One J2EE Design And Development](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/productCd-0764543857.html), despite hasn't archeological intentions, addressed some relevant issues on the language itself. He contrast it with .NET and stored procedures paradigms. But, I repeat, is a Java Developer book...

In addition, here is a [java timeline](http://www.java.com/en/javahistory/timeline.jsp)

And the java's father, James Gosling, [blog](http://nighthacks.com/roller/jag/)

Answer (score 1):

1. The [HOPL conference](http://research.ihost.com/hopl/HOPL-III.html) produced
   proceedings with papers from a bunch
   of really top guys, but unfortunatly
   none of the three editions contain
   any history on Java. However, the
   articles may still be of great use,
   as they provide a lot of insight
   into competing languages, which may
   help your student understand **why**
   Java is where it's at today.
2. The first chapter of [Programming
   Languages - Principles and
   Paradigms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072381116) consists of a very
   nice time line describing the
   evolution of the different languages
   and paradigms. This book is very
   easy to read and comprehend, so it
   might be a very good starting point.
3. Although I've not read [The History of
   Programming Languages](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201895021) myself,
   I know the authors of it, Bergin and Gibson, are both
   really good, so that might also be
   something of interest to your
   student.
4. For a nice overview, even if probably won't work in a reference list, I would recommend checking [this little article](http://www.woodger.ca/jv_evol.htm) out.
5. Finally, I want to recommend [this article](http://www.helium.com/items/1101180-the-history-of-java), mainly because it's both light and brief, but still to the point and comprehensive. It's probably also a good place to mine for references, which is always a good thing to learn how to do.

Good luck to you and your student!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one place to start:

http://ei.cs.vt.edu/book/chap1/java_hist.html

Answer (score 0):

One point to consider - some people make the distinction between Java as-a-platform (i.e., the JVM) and Java as-a-language.  Your student might find some divergent perspectives answering the questions from those different angles.